# Execute command in multiple sub-directories

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

Suppose I have folder structure like this

```
- Parent Folder/
       - code.sh
       - Child Folder 1/
             - Child Sub-Folder/
       - Child Folder 2/
       - Child Folder 3/
       - Child Folder 4/
```

I need some kind of bash script which will be placed in code.sh and will  **execute a command in Child Folder 1, Child Folder 2, Child Folder 3, Child Folder 4, etc.** But not in **Child Sub-Folder**

So far I have only found this solution

```
find ./* -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec git add -A {} \;
```

Give me this error

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

When I try this

```
find ./* -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec git add -A && git commit -m "My Message"{} \;
```

Give me this error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You should first initialize git repository in order to add something. Checkout https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: `git add  ./*/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and robust approach, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ./*/*/.git; do
    (
        cd "${dir%.git}"
        git add -A && git commit -m "My Message"
    )
done
```

Ensure you are at the same level than 'Parent Folder' directory.

A bit of explanations:

- the idea behind the snippet is to list all `.git` directory with a *glob* (wildcard) `./*/*/.git`
- `${dir%.git}` bash *parameter expansion*, remove `.git` substring
- the subshell `( )` is there to not having to explore the FS with `cd` to next dir. Each iteration is run in a new (sub)shell